# Дана последовательность из n целых чисел. Найти сумму элементов, в записи которых есть цифра 4

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Написала, следующий код:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int n, a,s=0,c;
    cout << "Input n" << endl;
    cin >> n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << "input a" << endl;
        cin >> a;
        int temp = a; 
        while (a > 0)
        {
            c = a % 10;
            a /= 10;
        }
        if (c == 4) s+= temp;
    }
    cout << s << endl;
}
```

но программа работает неправильно, подскажите, где ошибка?  а то никак разобраться не могу

Comment: как именно неправильно?

Comment: Сумма считается неправильно, не знаю почему

Comment: эта программы считает сумму только тех чисел, которые начинаются на 4. Учись элементарным способам поиска ошибок.

Comment: аа большое спасибо, сейчас попытаюсь исправить

Comment: сумма считается неправильно, потому что 4 может быть на любой позиции, а вы проходите цикл до конца и ловите 4 только в старшем разряде.

Comment: c = a % 10;
   if (c == 4) s+=temp;
   a /= 10; а если написать вот так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Перенесите обработку случая наличия 4 в цикл, вне его вы проверяете только последнюю цифру:

```
while (a > 0)
{
    c = a % 10;
    if (c == 4)  { s+= temp; break; } // Суммируем и выходим из цикла
    a /= 10;
}
    
while (a > 0)
{
    c = a % 10;
    if (c == 4)  { s+= temp; a = 0; } // Суммируем и выходим из цикла
    a /= 10;
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! Все работает!  А не подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно было программу сделать без break?)

Comment: Добавил в ответ. Между прочим, если он вам понравился (ответ то есть), его можно принять...

Comment: Ответ, правда, понравился! Ещё раз спасибо! Просто преподаватель по программированию требует сделать программы без break( я поэтому спросила)

Comment: А принять ответ вы так и не принимаете? Слева от ответа есть галочка, нажатие на которую и означает "большое спасибо". Просто спасибо - треугольник вверх.